# Rappid: implementing select2 field in the inspector, but it don't run the conditions "when"

Tags: events, jquery-select2, onchange, jointjs, rappid

I'm using Rappid to diagram relationship between objects.
I need to customize the inspector. I want to use select2 plugin to replace select-box when the values are too many.
To do that i used an example that appear in the documentation that use renderFieldContent to render the special fields
I define in the inspector.js my function and the object appear correctly, but in addition i need that another field appear when i had selected any value in mi select2, to do that I define the following "when"

```
when: {
       and: [
             { ne: { 'attrs/attributes/to_eval': '' } },
             { ne: { 'attrs/attributes/to_eval': null } },
            ]
      },
```

The problem is the following: When I change the selected option for the select2 the conditions is not validated.

How can i run the validation? I need to declare an event for select2, trigger an inspector event or i need to run the validation manually?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for those that may also be confused, I had to solve a similar problem with a field that needed to show up/hide when a `toggle` field was changed. This is what I did:

- added only one `ne` expression to the field that was supposed to show up/hide (`textOnToggle`);
- the `ne` expression path needed to point to the triggering field (`toggleText`);
- set a `defaultValue` on the triggering field.

Therefore, it is as simple as this:

```
textOnToggle: {
  type: 'content-editable',
  label: 'Text',
  index: 1,
  when: { ne: {'attrs/mypath/toggleText': true} },
},
toggleText: {
  defaultValue: false,
  type: 'toggle',
  label: 'Hide the text',
  index: 2,
},
```

So clicking the `toggleText` field in the inspector would, in this case, hide the `textOnTogle` field. You can change the boolean values to have the opposite action.

[JointJS expressions definition table](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v2.2/ui.html#ui.Inspector.definition-of-expressions) is a good reference to know which conditions can be added.